# Installing a cross-toolchain to build ARM binaries on Debian

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, gcc, arm, cross-compilation

I tried to install a cross toolchain so I could build Linux kernel on
amd64 (Debian testing "jessie") for my ARM system. I have this entry in `sources.list`:

```
deb http://www.emdebian.org/debian sid main
```

When I tried to install **gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi**, I got an error:

> cc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi : Depends: libgomp1-armel-cross (>=4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed

**libgomp1-armel-cross** in turn depends on **gcc-4.8-base-armel-cross** which
is not available anywhere.

At some point, I did manage to install these cross-build tools from the same repository, and even built a kernel that now runs on these ARM systems
some weeks ago. Is there something broken in that repository? I tried a few other versions of GCC, and still get the same issue.

A not-ideal solution is cross-building in an Ubuntu 12.04 VM. The distro has the ARM cross-compiler available from its official repositories.

Comment: [original post](https://lists.debian.org/debian-cross/2013/12/msg00000.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian now includes cross-toolchains officially, though they won't be part of the next Stable release (8.0). [Virtual packages are provided](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=crossbuild-essential).

Answer (score 5):

Emdebian repositories are recommended to be used in `stable` most of the time since there could be utilities not built in the repositories, packages that were pulled back, etc. If you want to ensure that all your libraries have the correct dependencies, I would suggest `stable` or `testing` since they are less likely to have some dependency problem or have something that got borked.

Comment: `stable` required me to enable `squeeze`, not `wheezy` as I expected. I also had to settle for **gcc-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabi**.

Comment: Hope you don't need a newer version of the toolchain D:.

Comment: Not really. This will do.

Comment: What does *borked* mean in this context?

Comment: @Tshepang [damage really bad something](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=borked‎)

Answer (score 1):

Stable does not help. The 4.7 - 4.8 inconsistency is still there. The inconsistency has existed for me since (around) version 4.4 of `gcc`.

Comment: Consider adding a source to confirm the existence of this inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do things in the "Linux way", which means for me, as less automatic configuration as possible.
I would download the required toolchain from the distributor’s site, and set a .CC file in your project's working dir. Your CC file should look something like this:

```
export PATH=< PATH-TO-TOOLCHAIN-BIN-FOLDER>:${PATH}
export CROSS_COMPILE=< TOOLCHAIN PREFIX` i.e "arm-none-gnueabi-" (the last "-" is important)
export ARCH=< ARCHITECTURE>
```

After doing that, before running any compilation, issue "source .CC", and then compile as you do normally, i.e "gcc/g++/ld... ...". The compilation will automatically use the toolchain (you will see it in the output of the compilation, that the toolchain is being used)